# unrecognized field when insert into table symfony2

Tags: symfony

I want to insert some data to my table like this:

```php
$x = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('xxxBundle:yyyy')
    ->findby(array($form->get('zzzz')->getData()));

foreach ($x as $xx) {
     $aaa = new aaaa();
     $aaa->setccccn(array($x));
}

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$em->flush();
```

When I do this, I got error `Unrecognized field: 0`.. help me please... what should i do??

Comment: Please show the complete error message. Don't you use `persist()` to save the entity in the DB?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here

```
->findby(
    array($form->get('zzzz')->getData())
);
```

You haven't given the findBy a key, so it's looking for column/field `0` which is the implied first key in a PHP array. `array($value)` is the same as `array(0 => $value)`

It should read something like this.

```
->findby(
    array('the_column_name' => $form->get('zzzz')->getData())
);
```

or this

```
->findbyTheColumnNameInCamelCase($form->get('zzzz')->getData());
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects